# App Crashing when using onCreate Eclipse [Beginner]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclick

This is so simple but I have no idea why it's crashing when I click a button.... It's meant to just change the TextView on the activity.

Code is below:::::

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.databasetut;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

private void displayText(String message) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
    textView.setText(message);

}



public void onClick_AddRecord(View v) {
    displayText("Clicked add record");
}
public void onClick_ClearAll(View v) {
    displayText("Clicked clear all");
}
public void onClick_DisplayRecords(View v) {
    displayText("Clicked display record");
}
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textDisplay"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.databasetut.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:onClick="onClick_DisplayRecords"
    android:text="Display" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClick_ClearAll"
    android:text="Clear" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:onClick="onClick_AddRecord"
    android:text="Add" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

What's the problem here?!

Comment: can you please add the error log? the stacktrace pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `android:id="@+id/textDisplay"` to both RelativeLayout and to TextView so error occurs.
Change the id of RelativeLayout or TextView your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that you're alowed to use uppercase letters in view Id's in your xml layout. So the fix will be to change `android:id="@+id/textDisplay"` to ex. `android:id="@+id/text_display"`. Plus remove `android:id="@+id/textDisplay"` from your `RelativeLayout` keep this id only on your textview